# try catch fails to handle segmentation fault inside a pthread

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, pthreads, try-catch

Here cdp is a package which has some vectors in it. When the vectors are accessed results in segmentation fault. (The vectors are accessed within its bounds I double checked it). I planned to handle this exception with try catch but its not working.

The following line is causing the problem according to gdb.

```
int firing_crash=cdp->firing_data[0].size();
```

Here is the function:

```
bool modified_simplex_solver::check_for_corrupt_cdp(converted_data_pack* cdp)
{
    try{
        int firing_crash=cdp->firing_data[0].size();
        int not_firing_crash=cdp->not_firing_data[0].size();
        return false;
    }
    catch(...)
    {   return true;}
}
```

Comment: You can only `catch` something that you `throw`. There is no `throw` here. A segfault is not a C++ exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `operator[]` (which does not perform bounds checking) and will result in undefined behavior if the vector does not have an element at the specified index, you can use the `at()` member function.

[`at( size_type pos );`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at)

This function:

> - Returns a reference to the element at specified location pos, with **bounds checking**.
> - If `pos` is not within the range of the container, **an exception of type `std::out_of_range` is thrown**.

Since an exception is thrown with `at()`, you can `catch` it.

The usage in your case will be:

```
int firing_crash=cdp->firing_data.at(0).size();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question uses exceptions for flow control. That's a Java thing; in C++ it's frowned upon. The way to do this in C++ (and in Java, as well) is to check whether the data exists:

```
return firing_data.empty() || not_firing_data.empty();
```